# Modify jQuery Autocomplete plugin to return new row when no results found

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

We're using the [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) for a friends lookup search with a static data set (i.e. we have the friends array loaded on the page and not via an AJAX lookup). We want to modify the plugin to inject a result when no results are found, something like a row with the name `Search for "Input Value" instead` but aren't having much luck.

Does anyone have a modified source that adds such a function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`response` callback](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response):

```
 $(function () {
     var list = [
         "a",
         "b"];
     $("#i").autocomplete({
         source: list,
         response: function (event, ui) {
             var results = ui.content;
             if (results.length === 0) {
                 results.push({
                     label: "Search for '" + $("#i").val() + "' instead"
                 });
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HjDfj/)

Comment: Like this answer a bit better than mine

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matt - 1) Man the jQuery docs look a lot better than they used to 2) does this work with the original '09 plugin that was later integrated into jQuery UI?

Comment: @RyanBrodie I had a quick look at the original plugin, and it I guess it won't work. You could still try it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the autocomplete with your own `source` function:

```
$(elem).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var noResults = [ { label: 'Search for "Input Value"', value: -1 } ];
        try {
            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
            var matchingFriends = $.grep(friendsArray, function(value) {
                // check if search token matches a friend
                if (matcher.test(value.username)) {
                    // add necessary properties for display in autocomplete
                    value.label = value.username;
                    value.value = value.id;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
            return matchingFriends;
        }
        catch (err) {
            response(noResults);
        }
        response(noResults)
    }
});
```

Check out the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L358) to see how this is implemented in jQuery-UI for more ideas.

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks for your answer. Again we're not using jQuery-UI but the original Autocomplete plugin that was written in 2009. As Matt's answer seems the most straightforward it's what I'm going to test first.